# iOS - Read the push notification once Received

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have 4 scenario

**When the app is not Launched**

Given the app was not Launched or Killed
When the push notification receive
And opened the app without tapping the notification
Then the app should capture the notification.

**When the app is running in foreground**

Given the app running in foreground
When the push notification receive
Then the app should capture the notification.

**When the app is running in background**

Given the app is running in background
When the push notification receive
And opened the app without tapping the notification
Then the app should capture the notification.

**When the app is not Launched and cleared the notification**

Given the app is not Launched or Killed
When the push notification receive
And user cleared the notification
And opened the app
Then the app should capture the notification.

The first 3 scenario works fine with the following code

The last scenario is not worked **When the app is not Launched and cleared the notification**

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: { requests in
            for request in requests {
                self.setNotification(userInfo: request.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary)
            }
        })
    }
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    setNotification(userInfo: userInfo as NSDictionary)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    setNotification(userInfo: userInfo as NSDictionary)
}
```

Comment: **YOU CAN'T**

Imagine you have 5 notifications on the screen. And you dismiss all 5 of them and then you launch the app. 

How should the app know which notification it should consider?

Comment: thanks @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: @Honey that was my question? is there any way to get those notification without restAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to your query**

> When the app is not Launched and cleared the notification
>
> Given the app is not Launched or Killed When the post notification
>   receive And user cleared the notification And opened the app Then the
>   app should capture the notification.

This is not possible for a **Normal Push notification** unless the user interacts with that notification. You may want to try **Silent notifications**, these are not shown in the UI but the control reaches the app and you can use the data/payload from there in your code.

When user clears the notification from bar, there is no way to fetch that information. 
You could also try to add the same information that is being sent in the push within an API and call it once the user opens the app.

[This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) deals with all the detail involved. According to your implementation, you can try a combination of both.

Comment: Thanks @Umar . I am using Silent notification. The only concern is notification is cleared. if there is no way have to get from API.

Comment: @Vignesh if you use an API as well for fetching data what would happen is that no matter user clears the notification, whenever the app opens the user would be able to see latest data as it would be coming via API call... Accept the answer if it helped